# How to make wx.Frame modal in wxPython (Phoenix)

Tags: wxpython

There used to be in wxPython 2

```
self.MakeModal(True)
```

But not in Phoenix.
How do I show it Modal? 
I do not want to use `wx.Dialog` because i need to add status bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a good work-around that I've used is to add the style flag `wx.FRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT` to the frame and disable the parent window via `frame.GetParent().Disable()`. Then bind the modal-like frame to `EVT_CLOSE` and re-enable the parent window via `frame.GetParent().Enable()`.

**------ Update -----**

Robin Dunn's suggestion is a more appropriate way to Modalize a frame.
From the [wx phoenix migration guide](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MigrationGuide.html#makemodal), add this to your Frame class

```
def MakeModal(self, modal=True):
    if modal and not hasattr(self, '_disabler'):
        self._disabler = wx.WindowDisabler(self)
    if not modal and hasattr(self, '_disabler'):
        del self._disabler
```

Comment: For another option see the MakeModal section in the Phoenix Migration Guide: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MigrationGuide.html#makemodal

Answer (score 0):

From a slightly different perspective, I found I had occasion to wait for a class that edited a database item, so I could re-read and present the changed data but I wanted that class to operate normally, in all other cases.

So it should be 'sort of` modal on request.

I found the easiest way, was to pass the class a parameter, if `True` it would immediately `Disable` the `parent`. then on exit, it would `Enable` the parent.

Meanwhile, the calling routine would loop on `self.IsEnabled()`

e.g.

Calling routine:

```
    OnNote(self, audio, "", modal=True)
    while not self.IsEnabled():
        wx.GetApp().Yield()
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Called class:

```
class OnNote(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, filename, database, modal=False):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, "Footswitch Notes")
        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        self.parent = parent
        self.modal = modal
        if self.modal:
            self.parent.Disable()
```

........

Exit called class:

```
    if self.modal:
        self.parent.Enable()
    self.Destroy()
```

It works a treat.